# How to revert a PR when there's no revert option on Github?

Tags: github

A PR was accidentally merged into main before it had been properly sanitized which I think has resulted in their being no revert option. The lack of an option suggests that it is not possible/simple?

https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/reverting-a-pull-request

I have write permissions to the repo in question.

Answer (score 1):

A revert is just a commit like any other commit. So, you can certainly revert the merge commit and push that, possibly as a PR if you're not able to push directly to main.

However, note that this reverses the *effect* of the merge without undoing the *topology*. You won't be able to merge those same commits again later.

In theory you can force main to go backwards to a commit before this bad merge took place, erasing the unwanted commits since then, or force main to point directly to the commit at the end of the good branch — namely by using a hard reset. But in practice, where you're sharing this repo with others, that would be a pretty terrible idea.

Comment: Not to counter matt, as he is right on the money. Just want to add that rewriting those revisions that had been originally merged so that they are not merged anymore (by `rebase -i` trickery, for example) is not that hard to achieve.

Comment: I think this is the problem, The PR isn't a single commit it was about 100 and there have been periodic merges of main back into the PR. The intention was to squash everything at the end. Where I do `git revert` I can undo a single commit sure but this doesn't revert the entire PR.

Comment: I guess I am also interested in why GH doesn't give us the revert option here

Comment: @Goods That would be a matter of opinion. But perhaps your expectations are mistaken? GitHub isn't Git. It's just a hosting web site. It isn't GitHub's job to imitate or provide a GUI for every Git feature, nor does it try to do so. Why should it?

Comment: And even if it did, how would that be different from the revert commit you make yourself? A commit is a commit, regardless of where it comes from.

Comment: As for the multiple merges of main back into the PR, I don't see what difference that makes to my answer. The only thing that affects main is the merge into main, and the revert commit undoes that, as I said in my answer.

Comment: It's true that there's a GitHub doc about a Revert button — and that doc also states very clearly the conditions under which the Revert button will and won't appear. By the way, I didn't talk about that doc in my answer because you didn't mention it in your question. The question I answered is the question you asked. The question said you can't revert the merge, and I said yes you absolutely can. And I stand by that.